# Join GA table with a normal table on date field in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to join in BigQuery some GA sessions tables with one normal table on all the dates between two date fields (Start and End) in my normal table. My goal is to obtain for each session the time, the fullVisitorId, the day that session took place and other infos relative to that date that are stored in the normal table. The normal table has 3 columns Start(datetime), End(datetime), Event(string). This is what i've done:

```
SELECT * FROM `normal_table` as A
JOIN (
   SELECT fullVisitorId, MAX(h.time)/1000 SessionTime,date FROM `analytics_table.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) as h 
   WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20211207' AND '20211213'
   ) AS B
ON PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", B.date) Between DATE(A.Start) AND DATE(A.END)
```

The problem is that i think i am duplicating observations with this type of join or something else is going wrong because i have lots of rows duplicated.

Comment: When you unnest the hits, it'll seem like you have lots of duplicate rows. Try adding in h.hitNumber the numbers should be unique and different per session.

Comment: Hi @DataShytter, To avoid duplication you can include group by fullVisitorId and date in the subquery.
If this doesn't solve the issue, please provide the schema and sample data of the tables `normal_table` and `ga_sessions` that you are using.

Comment: Did the above comments help you in resolving the issue?